# Rails logger configuration - show the code line that makes a query to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built a quite big rails application. Now I have a lot of queries on some pages. I'd really like the rails development log to show what line in my code that made the query request so I easy could remove some.

This is what I want.

```
[called from ProjectsController.rb line 32]CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE "firms"."subdomain" = 'testing' LIMIT 1
```

Is there a tag to put in the config/environments/development.rb file

This would be great!

```
config.log_tags = [:code_line_call]
```

Comment: Don't think it is possible to capture line numbers like this from your controllers. The alternative would be to put in `logger.debug` entries with tags before any reference to a model in your controller actions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to get the code line in the log.

The solution was [Miniprofiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby)

It is a great tool for finding sql requests in your code

Ryan Bates made a railscast about it

[railscasts 368-miniprofiler](http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler)

Answer (score 1):

A more lightweight solution is [Active Record Query Tracer](https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace/tree/master)
Which does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The question is 5 years old. I bet there is a lot of new solutions to the problem.